# How to remove first link from string?

Tags: php

How to remove first link with image from this text with PHP?

```
<a href="some link"><img src="image link" /></a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.**
```

Comment: Can you restate clearly what you need to accomplish, and whether this text is coming from a database, xml, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by splitting the line by the '>' character..

PHP:

```
$line = "<a href=''><img src=''></a>blah blah blah";
$parts = explode('>', $line);
```

If you wanted the image....

```
$img = $parts[1].">";
```

If you want just the text...

```
$text = $parts[3];
```

Comment: It's dirty... but if your question really is THAT simple of a question, that'll work.

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = '<a href="some link"><img src="image link"></a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<a href="some link"><img src="image link"></a>';

// strip the entire <a> tag including contents (first occurrence only)
$str = preg_replace('/<a.*?<\/a>/', '', $str, 1); 

// strip only the <a> leaving the inner HTML (first occurrence only)
$str = preg_replace('/<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/', '$1', $str, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
$link = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);
$link->parentNode->removeChild($link);
$html = $doc->saveHTML();
```